# I cannot copy the token of jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Hi I loaded Jupyter from Anaconda Prompt, with "jupyter notebook" command

Then it prompted me to enter the link with token, to open the notebook (it opened the notebook page on IE default browser, but I wanted to open in Chrome)

But here is the problem: I cannot select and copy text from Anaconda Prompt; The link is not in clipboard automatically either.

How can I get the link and run it in Chrome one way to the other?

Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjx3v.png)

Answer (score 4):

Right click on Title Bar and select Properties. Check on 'Quick Edit Mode'
This worked for me after reading this for [Windows Command Prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem when tried to relocate my Jupyter notebook from Microsoft browser to Chrome. Here's what I did.

1. Let the Notebook open up on your default browser.
2. Right-click on the notebook anywhere and click on Inspect.
3. The terminal will open up on the right side below the Element section a Token ID will appear.
4. copy that token by double-clicking on it.
5. Paste it on the required jupyter server.